# Configure ADFS for Dynamics AX 2012 Mobile Connector

Tags: adfs2.0, windows-server-2012, iis-8, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, servermanager

I've been trying to install and configure dynamics AX mobile solution by following the instructions mentioned in the Whitepaper [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36776)

On page 12 where you can validate if your service is set up correctly by opnening the url: `https://localhost/adfs/fs/federationserverservice.asmx`

i get the HTTP error 503 saying that the service is unavailable. I even tried to open these URL: `https://localhost/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed`, `https://localhost/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml` but it gave me the same error message. The IIS application pool for the ADFS is running. The ADFS Windows Server is running.

The funny thing is that the "Workflow approval via email" is working.
The ADFS is installed/added through Server Manger on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the event viewer logs. You see the 503 error when there is a port conflict. Some other service is most likely using the same port, so even though ADFS says it has started, there is still a port conflict that you need to resolve. This is a great way to fix it:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2009.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-change-the-net-tcp-ports-for-services-and-administration.aspx

Hope this helps!